# Create a model from a table containing a TIME column

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, webforms

I have an Web Forms application using Entity Framework 6.1.3, which is the latest one available in Nuget for Web Forms.

I loaded a table to the EF model from SQL Server that has a column of type "time" but Entity Framework sends a warning:

> Warning 1 Error 6005: The data type 'time' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'IMPORTANT_TIME' in table 'tablename' was excluded.

All other columns of the same table were imported correctly.

My DB is SQL Server 2012. (I cannot edit this DB at all)

Is there a Work around?

Comment: Do you actually need the column? What workarounds are viable? In what format do you want to read the data? Can you add a computed column to the table, or to a view that reads from the table?

Comment: 1 Yes, I need the column. 2 I don't know any work around thats why I am asking. 3 format, the same from sql i guess 4 how does a computed column helps? (I cannot edit the table in the database)

Comment: You can add a view that transforms the time column into a supported type. You could use an SqlCommand.